# Adding a reference to "Microsoft PowerPoint 14.0 Object Library" in MS-Access causes "Name conflicts with existing module, project, or object library"

Tags: vba, ms-access, powerpoint, typelib

I am trying to add a reference to *Microsoft PowerPoint 14.0 Object Library* in an MS-Access project so that I can use the object model of PowerPoint.

When I do that, I get an *Name conflicts with existing module, project, or object library*. The only two type library references currently used by this MS-Access Projects are *Visual Basic for Applications* and *Microsoft Access 14.0 Object Libary*, both of which I cannot de-reference.

Is there a way to add the PowerPoint reference without such a conflict?

Comment: It conflicts with some other reference you have. If you post what other references you have, someone could point you to the conflicting reference.

Comment: I already have posted those references: `Visual Basic for Applications` and `Microsoft Access 14.0 Object Libary`

Comment: Silly question, perhaps, but sometimes Office and Windows get silly and need silly answers to sort them out:   Have you restarted your PC?

Comment: @SteveRindsberg this seemed indeed to be the problem. After restarting the PC this morning, this Problem went away. You might want to turn your comment into an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: unbelievable... :)

Comment: I'd feel guilty taking credit for such a silly thing.  ;-)